# Issue with Pulsar GeoReplication

Tags: apache-pulsar, pulsar, geo-replication, spring-pulsar

I have followed the steps and completed the Geo replication setup as per the pulsar documentation
https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/3.1.x/administration-geo/
All the geo replication related setup was enabled and working fine.
When I try to produce a message from the US-WEST cluster , I am unable to consume it from the US-EAST.
Can someone please help me to fix the issue.

When I try to produce a message from the US-WEST cluster, I am unable to consume it from the US-EAST.

Comment: Hi @sathiskumar-perumal, are you using Spring for Apache Pulsar? I see the question is tagged w/ spring-pulsar and that is a tag that I follow and try to answer questions on promptly. If you are just using straight Pulsar you may be able to get help on the Pulsar slack channel apache-pulsar.slack.com

Answer (score 0):

First, you can check the topic stats which will provide you the backlogs of the replicator. If there is no backlog of the replicator, the messages should be replicated to the remote cluster.

bin/pulsar-admin topics stats  can be used to get the topic stats (on US-WEST cluster)

Second, you need to check the initial position that you used to create the consumer point to the US-EAST cluster. The consumer will use latest position as the initial position to subscribe to the topic, so if you don't have new messages published to the topic after the consumer connected, you will not receive any messages in this case.

To resolve the second issue, you can try publish more messages after the consumer connected (you can also create a subscription before publishing messages via admin API) or use the earliest position as the subscription initial position.